# DateTime.Parse sometimes throws FormatException over Pipes

Tags: c#, datetime, named-pipes

I am trying to send a DateTime from one process to another. My first thought was to send the DateTime as a string and parse the string back to DateTime onces received. Unfortunately on some machines I get a FormatException even though the string looks good e.g. "31.10.2019 12:00:00" (no hidden characters).

The code looks like this, I will omit the communication since the string is correctly transferred.

```
var datetimeAsString = SomeDateTime.ToString();      // "31.10.2019 12:00:00"
Pipe.Send(StringToBytes(datetimeAsString));
// Data gets send
var datetimeAsString = BytesToString(receivedBytes); // "31.10.2019 12:00:00"
var datetime = DateTime.Parse(datetimeAsString);
```

Please note that it works on some machines.

Comment: instead, why don't you use `DateTime.ParseExact`?

Comment: You should be using ISO8601 format for transferring date/times.  DateTime.ToString("o") will give you yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ, which is universally understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

When trying to send DateTime between different systems, do **NOT** convert it to a string using ToString() without parameter use [DateTime.ToBinary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tobinary) and [DateTime.FromBinary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.frombinary) instead OR if you want a string specify a culture e.g.

```
var datetimeAsString = thisDate.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-us"));
DateTime.Parse(datetimeAsString, new CultureInfo("en-us"));
```

PS: I think this not only applies to situations where you want to exchange data but also to other situations and therefore should be seen as a general advice.

--

The problem was that the software that sent the DateTime converted the DateTime.ToString() to a German format, even though the software was in English. The receiving software was sometimes in German and sometime in English. The software with the German language was able to use DateTime.Parse on the German string, the other systems weren't.

The solution was to not convert the DateTime to a string but to a long using the DateTime.ToBinary method. I think is would also been possible to solve it with CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, but we thought long was much cleaner.

Comment: Be careful; as the documentation explains, `.ToBinary()` and `.FromBinary()` may adjust the actual value based of local times so they are "correct" in the local time zone. This may or may not actually be what you want; to prevent surprises you may want to serialize a `DateTime` value in universal time only (i.e. call `.ToUniversalTime()` first). If time zone information is actually necessary, using a `DateTimeOffset` would be a better idea, as it removes surprises by being explicit about the time zone.

Comment: OPs problem is a culture problem. But he should _NOT_ stick to a specific culture, but instead use a neutral format like @neil suggested. To stick to a specific culture solves only a part of the problems that can occur with Date to String to Date conversion

Comment: @JeroenMostert to be precise _DateTimeOffset_ has no information about the timezone. It only stores the offset from local time to universal time. Besides that, it is very useful to handle timezone problems. Still, if textual representation is needed, a culture independent format like the ISO format should be used

Comment: @DanielSchmid: yes, if you really need the actual time zone itself you're looking at libraries like Noda Time. For adjustment purposes the offset is enough, of course.